# Skip uniqueness validation for nil class Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, null

Currently, I can't create an empty field with nil value, because nil counts as unique. I want to do if field has value then it must be unique if nil then not and also it can't return an empty string value.

This is my validation:

```
validates :subdomain, :allow_nil => true, uniqueness: true
```

**Update**

With this validation I get an error message:

> Subdomain can't be blank

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :subdomain, presence: true, allow_nil: true, if: -> (x) { x.subdomain.present? }
```

Without "presence: true" in console, I can create a record with subdomain nil value, but if I do this in a browser, it creates subdomain with empty string.

Comment: Try `validates :subdomain, :allow_nil => true, uniqueness: true, if: '!subdomain.nil?'`

Comment: Maybe you have unique constraint on the DB level? Which error do you get when trying to save a second record with nil value?

Comment: No subdomain simple string. Error message: "Subdomain has already been taken"

Answer (score 2):

As @Pavan has said in a comment, you'll need to run this validation conditionally.

Because of the `:allow_nil` option, `nil` is an accepted value; however, it will still run the uniqueness test against this value unless you add on the additional check.

I would use the following code:

```
validates :subdomain, allow_nil: true, uniqueness: true, if: -> (x) { x.subdomain.present? }
```

Presonally, I feel `present?` is a nice, readable way of including this.

With this in place, I'm 99% certain you'll also be able to do away with the `:allow_nil` option, using simply:

```
validates :subdomain, uniqueness: true, if: -> (x) { x.subdomain.present? }
```

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions.

---

Edit based on comment, here is an example to reject empty strings:

```
validates :subdomain, allow_nil: true, uniqueness: true, presence: true, if: :subdomain
# or
validates :subdomain, uniqueness: true, presence: true, if: :subdomain
```

Again, don't think you'll need the `:allow_nil` in there: I've updated the conditional so the validation runs simply on `record.subdomain`, which will return `true` for an empty string, `false` for `nil`.

Comment: It almost works, just It creates record with empty string, not nil value.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Kristis - in which case, ensure you have `:allow_nil` in there, and add `presence: true` to the options. That way `nil` will be allowed, though an empty string won't. I'll update my answer with a full example :)

Comment: Subdomain has already been taken,
Subdomain can't be blank. I get this with this validation: validates :subdomain, allow_nil: true, uniqueness: true, presence: true, if: :subdomain

Comment: Could you do me a favour a post the form and params received by the controller in the question? I've got to dash for a bit, though if you add that, it's likely someone will be able to help, or I can when back.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

controller create method

```
@organisation = Organisation.new(params[:organisation].delete_if{ |key, value| !value.present? })
```

and in model:

```
validates   :subdomain, :allow_nil => true, uniqueness: true
```